# Can I pass my mnemonic to ganache/ ganache-cli when it is starting up?

Tags: ganache, ganache-cli, mnemonic

I am wondering if I can pass the mnemonic that I created using metamask to boot up my local ganache network so that I do not have to log out and login metamask with different mnemonic everytime for a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are booting up ganache-cli, you can pass your mnemonic using `-m` or `-menmonic`. In ganache desktop app with UI, instead of doing quickstart, use New Workspace and navigate to ACCOUNT&KEYS Tab. There is a field to pass your mnemonic.